# Change the Image Size without changing its Place Holder

Tags: android, image, size

I have some ImageView in a Horizontal LinearLayout. I set their size in percentage mode.

```
<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/pjc_news_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now if I install my software in a small size device, the width of images will get smaller to fit specified percent of their parent layout. their height will get smaller too. but their place holder's height doesn't change. I mean they have an useless blank space in their bottom.

Comment: please paste your complete xml here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

I added the "adjustViewBounds" property to my ImageView and set it's value true. then the space below the ImageView removed.

```
<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/pjc_news_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding another view so that it covers up the remaining space.

```
<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.25"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:src="@drawable/pjc_news_icon" />

<View 
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_weight="0.75"   
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Just give a try to this, hop it works for you.